# How to identify the which marker user tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have multiple markers on google maps. how to identify the marker tapped, when user clicks on marker?

Answer (score 0):

See this link.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Because of setting addListner to each marker, you identify tapped marker.

Comment: I need it in IOS

Comment: oops, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the delegate for GMSMapView, specifically this method: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#ae291e1bff99f9d06428ced09daf5802d

You get the instance of the tapped marker in the method, so use that to identify which marker it is and how it relates to your data.